# scrollIntoView/scrollTo when used inside iframe is not responding in IOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, angular7

I have an application thats displays on a website using iframe.

Please see this jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/7Leatwyu/

Here is also a stackblitz that has a similar code setup as my angular app
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2dnea

Here youll see ive tried a few things like adding CSS styling to account for scrolling including:

```
position: absolute; 
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom:0;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
z-index: 1000;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

When you answer a question or click the next button, it uses the code below to scrollTo the correct next question. As youll see - for every device aside from iPhone (IOS) it works. For IOS - it does not work.

```
scrollTo(el): void {
    const element = document.querySelector(`#${el}`)
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
  }
```

After this is called im expecting the window to scroll to the next question but it doesnt. Are there any work arounds out there? Ive been researching this for a week now and have tried many different javascript and CSS solutions that did not work.

Help..

Comment: I tested on my IOS device and it works. Not the same animation but I can't find anything wrong. Maybe you fix it already?

Comment: How do you call the `scrollTo` function? What value has the `el` parameter? What is your HTML code (structure)?

Comment: So those links up there no longer go to the version that wasnt working. I had to redo the entire flow to get it to work (not the scrollTo but the UI). @HerrSerker The scrollTo is called on click. The el is the string that I use to find the element to scroll to. And the html structure is an angular template. It uses the (click) event binder to call the scrollTo function which scrolls to the element itself

Answer (score 0):

I do hate multiple browsers. Makes life as web designer a pain.

Anyway [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll) `scrollIntoView` Doesn't have the best support on **OLDER** safari browsers. Still isnt 100% on newer ones.

Would it be possible to use jquery??

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("div.top").offset().top
}, 1000)
```

Like so?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#submit').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".somediv").offset().top
    }, 1000)
  })
});
```

```css
.somediv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"><br />
<a id="submit" href="#">Submit</a>
<div class="somediv"></div>
```

I don't know if this is exactly what your trying to achieve. Just another way at looking at the scroll to next.

You can always wrap it in an if statement first :)